# Do I have to chunk large data while sending it with tcp socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm sending some not to large strings over tcp socket. Today I send 2031 bytes and receiving end didn't get it all (I've send bigger messages - before 2040 bytes to days ago) - this isn't all that bad, program knew that something was wrong and send the data again (3rd try was successfull). Now I'm wondering if I should split message into smaller chunks and send them in loop statement? Is there something in my code that I'm missing?

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sock.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout,0);
sock.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.SendTimeout,0);           
LingerOption lingerOption = new LingerOption (true, 1); 
sock.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.Linger, lingerOption );
sock.Blocking =  true;

try
{
    sock.Connect(_dostHostEp);
}
catch(SocketException e)                     
{                                       
    sock.Close();
    throw new Exception("Connection error (" + _dostHostEp.Address + ":" + _dostHostEp.Port + ")" + e.Message);             
}

try    
{
    sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));                             
}
catch(SocketException e)
{                   
    sock.Close();               
    throw new Exception("Error while sending message to (" + _dostHostEp.Address + ":" + _dostHostEp.Port + ")" + e.Message);               
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Async Sockets Server Receive Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934469/c-sharp-async-sockets-server-receive-problems)

Comment: The duplicate says "async", but the problem is really the same thing. Read my answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist to get the 2031 bytes in one chunk? Rather, you'd have to read the data at the receiver side **until** data exists. This means that for example you read a chunk of 1800 bytes, another chunk of 231 bytes and then 0 bytes which means end of the data.

Comment: -1 No. 0 do not mean end, it means "disconnect". `Read` will not return until more data is available.

Comment: I'm not insisting on getting 2031 bytes in one chunk. Receiving is done by someone else. My question is if there is a limit of byte array passed in socket.Send method?

Comment: Read my linked answer. You can never guarantee that the receiver receives everything as you sent it. TCP do not work like that. In other words: it doesn't really matter how much data you send (as long as you don't overflow the socket implementations internal buffer).

Comment: so overall my way is not that bad: 1. send 2. see if it went ok (receiver response with proper message) 3. if not send again later?

Comment: TCP will always deliver what you sent (or die trying = disconnect) = you never need to resend anything. You need to introduce a way to tell the receiver when a message begins or ends (again, read the linked answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've always considered sending data without a well defined end character bad practice. I would personally recommend doing the following:

As the sender, prepend the message with an STX-Character (0x02) and append the ETX-Character (0x03).

The receiver should recognize STX as the start of a new message and then read (blocking?) until an ETX is received. If no ETX is received in reasonable time, there was a problem reading the entire message.

You don't need to use STX and ETX, you might also use \r\n or anything that is not part of your message itself.

If you do not use a well defined end of message, the reader will never know when to stop reading and you will mess up your communication.

One sample case I've indentified as problematic:

The sender sends two messages one after the other. Without an EndOfMessage-character, the receiver will try to read this as one single message. With an EOM, the receiver can split the two messages and handle them both.

Comment: why not vote to close as a duplicate instead of repeating my answer in the linked question?

Comment: Because I started writing this reply before you even made the comment about the duplicate.